# how to restart a grails web application

Tags: grails, groovy, jetty

how can I restart a grails application other than shutting it down by doing ctrl z and running it again.

when I do it that way it says

```
Error Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use
```

Comment: Sounds like you are not waiting long enough for the server to shutdown - there are probably some processes which get triggered on shutdown (catching SIGHUP) and you need to wait for them to finish before re-running the run-app command.

Comment: @nickdos i gave some time and it still does the same thing. is there a way i can manually shut down the jetty web server that is built in to grails?

Comment: Depending on your platform, you should be able to find the active process for jetty and simply kill that process with a high "kill factor". E.g. for Mac OS X and Linux, it would `kill -9 <pid>`, where <pid> is the process number. Can't remember how to do it on Windows, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't shut down an application, sends a [SIGTSTP signal to the process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTSTP) to suspend it...  Suspended processes still have connections to their resources (ports, files, etc), so you cannot run another instance of grails on the same port whilst one is suspended.

To bring it back [to the foreground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fg_%28Unix%29), you can enter `fg` in the same shell (or if you want it to [run in the background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bg_%28Unix%29), you can use `bg`)

To shut it down, you need <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (or you can kill it as nickdos says in the comments)

Comment: Ctrl+C doesn't always work if it's hung. Check @IanRoberts answer below.

Comment: .kill-run-app and kill <pid> doesn't always work every time. See my other post on kill -9 12345 to really smash it.

Comment: Just `Ctrl + C` doesn't wok when executed with `--debug--fork`, it doesn't kill the actual process where the Grails app is running. To properly stop it, use `grails stop-app` instead.

Answer (score 5):

To cleanly shut down a `run-app` or `run-war`, create an empty file named `.kill-run-app` in the top-level directory of your grails application (i.e. alongside `grails-app`, `src`, etc.).  Grails will automatically delete this file once the application has been stopped, so don't be surprised when it disappears shortly after you created it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Grails 3. See [this answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22673925/539048)

Answer (score 3):

Shutdown should not require process hacking and doesn't require a 'could ruin everything' disclaimer :)

Just run:

`grails stop-app`

Comment: It's also working in Grails 2.5.6. This is the proper answer. Just Ctrl + C doesn't kill the actual process where the Grails app is running, at least in a case when executed with `--debug--fork`.

Answer (score 2):

If that still doesn't work:

`lsof -i :8080` or `ps aux | grep grails`

Will show the process id, then first try killing it nicely:

`kill 12345` (where 12345 is the processId)

Of if it really doesn't want to play nicely, then **HAMMER** it with:

`kill -9 12345` (where 12345 is the processId)

Works every time (DISCLAIMER: Could ruin everything)